# Users.threads.modify returns 404 not found for existing threads

Tags: gmail, gmail-api

I've got an application that labels message automatically. This is a nodejs application that depends on the latest version of `googleapis` and `google-auth-library` npm library. It is certain authentication went correctly because I'm able to create labels and fetch thread list.

I observed a scenario, that `Users.threads.modify` returns 404 'not found' even though the thread exists. When that happens, `Users.messages.insert`  may return 404 too when inserting to a specified thread.

It's difficult to reproduce this issue. In one case, I discovered this may have something to do with 'Send As' alias configured in the user's account. For accounts with aliases configured years ago, maybe decades ago, such problem exists. When the user removed the 'Send As' alias, and added them again, the problem went away.

This problem did not happen to users with newer accounts.

The API error response is not so intuitive. The full error is:

```
{  
    code:404,
    errors:[  
        {  
            domain:'global',
            reason:'notFound',
            message:'Not found'
        }
    ]
}
```

What can I do if Gmail API says 404 when I'm positive that thread exists?

Comment: Please share HTTP requests made for Gmail API.

Comment: I mentioned I'm using the API through the `googleapis` library. You want to see the function calls and payload?

Comment: Hey @HeShiming,
I'm running on the same issue as you and would like to know if you were able to solve it and know the reason.